# How do I set values from ArrayList to JTextField using button?

Tags: java, jtextfield, jlist

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter =new FileNameExtensionFilter ("Text/Java files","txt","java");
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
String str;

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(str);
}
String[] listArray =list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
for (int b=0; b<listArray.length;b++) {
    String[] Arra= str.split(" ");

    jTextfield1.setText(Arra.get(0));
    jTextfield2.setText(Arra.get(0));
```

Comment: If you accept the answer, mark it as accepted (V symbol under answer score)

Comment: Why do you have this line in its position. String[] Arra= str.split(" "); According to your for loop you should have maybe listArray.get(b).split(" ");

Comment: What's the structure of your text file?

Comment: @sedrick it looks like this-SNo: 2509182, Pin No: 4769 2639 3118 3473 CHKCode: 52539-

Comment: I suggest you hold back on the textfields for a second and use System.out.println(). Using this appraoch you can see right away if your program is printing the correct info and if your program is correct up to this point. Once you can see that things are running smooth, replace your System.out.println(); with jtextfield.setText(); Also, you need to practice/think hard about program flow. Your flow is off.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, change your bufferedReader to this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));//remove quotes around filename
```

You were trying to create a `FileReader` from a file called `filename` and not from the file name itself

`Arra` is an array but you use it as a list.

Do this instead:

```
if(Arra.length > 1){
    jTextfield1.setText(Arra[0]);
    jTextfield2.setText(Arra[1]); 
}
```

The if statement is important because `Arra` might not have an index of 0 or 1

Comment: it didn't work but thanks anyway

Comment: @Narciss what happens when you run it? did you try to debug?

Comment: i have and still getting nothing

Comment: @Narciss again, what happens when you run it?

Comment: it runs fine but the jtextfield turn up empty after i load the file

Comment: @Narciss fixed now

Comment: I didn't catch the quotes. Good catch.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson thank you :P